# Wordpress user frontend Plugin Posts listing order by title?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

We are using "Wordpress user frontend Plugin" in our site to create, edit posts from frontend.
There we need a feature which is not implemented in the plugin we guess.
We need to show the posts listing by their titles regardless of their creation date.

Can it be possible?if yes, then can please let us know the correct way of using an action hook or filter rather than made the changes directly on the plugin files itself.

Really needed a quick response,already spending a lot of hours for this one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the index page, including `'orderby'=> 'title'` in the correct place.

A [quick google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=order%20posts%20by%20title%20wordpress&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB726GB726&oq=order%20posts%20by%20title%20wordpress&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0.7649j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will find the exact answer you need. Do your research.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for the Quick response but we are using a plugin here.
Everything is in shortcodes and we can't pass additional parameters to those shortcodes for sorting.

Anyway thanks

Comment: So here's how I understand it to work:

* User creates a post on the front end
* View the posts page, their post is there
* You want this page ordered by title?

Answer (score 0):

finally after going through the plugin(Wordpress user frontend) files.
I got this filter "wpuf_dashboard_query".
applied my necessary changes to it and it worked.

```
add_filter('wpuf_dashboard_query','wpuf_posts_sort_by_title');

  function wpuf_posts_sort_by_title($args){
    $data = array_merge($args, array('orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'DESC'));
    return $data;
  }
```